# Review page instructions overflow their box

Tags: bug, status-completed, formatting

I just took a look at https://english.stackexchange.com/review, and there's an oops:

[image: the last line of text doesn't fit in the box]

Comment: I suppose I should have added a nice red freehand circle, but I'm too lazy.

Comment: I'll put in a fix for this soon. I'll reserve the "fancy box" for new user greetings only. For the Review tip box, I'll make it to have the same styling as the tip boxes on the Ask Question page.

Comment: nobody said that it must be *nice*. Or red, for that matter. (It can be [green and completely fall over](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67754/ive-gained-the-privilege-to-vote-up-on-stack-overflow/67759#67759).)

Comment: @RegDwight: Really? Nobody said they have to be red? (And you're sure that's not just an unwritten rule?)

Answer (score 1):

I see that too, but only at some font sizes. When I go from smaller font to larger, I get this: ... bad-**good**-bad-bad-bad-**good**-bad... that is probably why this was overlooked.